# How Install Mvc forum nuget package Existing package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I Have develop MVC 5 project and I want one more page in my project
   Discussion forum. I have searched MVC forum nuget package best for
   develop forum.

How to install MVC Forum nuget package Existing
   Project? I have tried, but I am getting Error My Existing Project. How to
   add MVC Forum on my Existing project?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  And how are you adding the NuGet reference - from the command line console?

Comment: using Visual Studio 2015 and  adding   command line using install-package MvcForum

Comment: At the top of the command line box there is a drop-down where you can select the project to install it to.  But to be honest, in VS2015 you're better off using the Nuget Package Manager window rather than the console, as it's a massive improvement over 2012.

Comment: actually i have develop one  project everything finished now i want add Forum in   project.i trying to add forum using MVCforum   package using  its generate code but my old project was not showing